# How to remove directory name from url with global.asax code

Tags: model-view-controller, url-rewriting, asp.net-mvc-routing

I am using MVC routing in asp.net Web forms and I want to remove the folder/directory name appended in the URL.  Locally this works fine but I have the following address now appearing on Godaddy shared hosting.

www.mywebsite.com/my-folder/contact

but I want like this

www.mywebsite.com/contact

I have tried web.config techniques but no success that's why I am asking is there any way to redirect this using Global.asax.

Comment: Please see this link: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd329551%28v=vs.100%29.aspx